# How to handle POST call with JSON having data with "parent-child" relationship using ASP.NET Web API Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, post, asp.net-web-api2

I have a JSON which has a format as given below:

```
{
"header": {
"source_code": "S12345"
"user_id": "987456"
},
"body":{
"source_code": "S12345",
"wrapper_list": [
{
"item_wrapper_code": "WRAP01",
"item_amount": 10,
"item_type_amount": 2,
"creation_date": 20191115,
"worker": "W001",
"workstation_no": "1"
"item_list":[
{
"item_code": "I001"
"item_id": "",
"bar_code": "123987456"
"remark": ""
},
{
"item_code": "I002"
"item_id": "",
"bar_code": "213987456"
"remark": ""
}
]
}
]
}
}
```

The body of the above  JSON object contains data in a parent - child relationship.

```
Parent: WRAP01
Child1: Item I001
Child2: Item I002
```

I must be able to parse this JSON object and insert these details as rows into respective tables, i.e., Parent related stuff into Parent table and Children related stuff into Child table.

I request professionals here to kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

So, parsing Json to Entity Framwork objects is bad practise.

Firstly, create data transfer objects (DTO) that will  be maps to Json.
It is like:
RequestDto, BodyDto, WrapperDto, WrapperItemDto.

For parse it you can use something like newtonsoft, see example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Then you should write EntityFramework objects that will be maps to Database tables. 
I hope, you knows Databases theory and already reads some articles about EntityFramework and how it implements different DB relationsips. If no, so please read about it.

You needs One-To-Many relationship. The one-to-many relationship can be configured in the following ways.

1. By following Conventions
2. By using Fluent API Configurations

You can use first way. Its more easy. So you need 2 classes: WrapperEntity, WrapperItemEntity.

Then, you should write code that will convert WrapperDto to WrapperEntity and WrapperItemDto to WrapperItemEntity. And then save *Entity objects in database.

It's a best practise for implements such logic. I explain it as top level. For details you can google each question separately.